# How can i send a form with node.js without the web starts loading?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express, response

Sorry for my bad english, i'm studying to improve it.

I'm new in node.js and i want to send many forms to a mongoDB database without the web starts loading something and never stop, i think it's searching the response and isn't exist a response (and i don't want to send a response, i only want to send forms) I can send all of i want and works correctly, but i think is not tidy that that occurs.
In the moment i press the submit button, the web starts loading
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxcXV.jpg)

index.ejs:
i have a form with method="POST" and action="/addProduct"

routes.js:
`router.post('/addProduct', controller.addProduct)`

controllers.js:
`export const addProduct = async (req) => { const newProduct = Product(req.body);    -> mongoose model await newProduct.save();`

Thanks!

I tried different ways but i can't resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make xhr requests to avoid page loading.

in your form make the submit button type as button:

```
<form>
  ///form input element
  <label for="fname">First name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="postForm()">
</form>
```

```
<script>
function postForm(){
let field1 = document.getElementById("fname").value
fetch('http://localhost:3000/post/addProduct', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "field1": field1 })
})
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
}
</script>
```

then get the form data in `req.body.field1` in your /post/addProduct route. Make sure you are using body parser properly.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, you help me a lot! (I unintentionally deleted the previous comment)